# Img placement and text underneath on navbar as well as a solid line

Tags: html, css, navbar

I want to show 3 images on the top portion of a navbar followed by text directly underneath the image and centered.  In my code I have the 3 images.  They happen to be spaced evenly however I am not sure if that is a coincidence or if I need to specify the image placement programmatically.

Also as for the text, my code shows the code to the right of the last image instead of underneath in the center as it should be.  Finally I want to show a solid line underneath the text to segment it from the rest of the website

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 
      <img src="/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      Bootstrap_Left
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 
      <img src="/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      Bootstrap_center
    </a>    
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 
      <img src="/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block  align-text-top">
      Bootstrap_right
    </a>     
    <div align="center">My Site<br>Po Box 12, My State</div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not following correctly I do apologize, but I am going to try and guess at what you're describing above.. This is just to get you started, but flexbox is the way to go. Once you figure out flexbox the possibilities are almost endless. Here's the video I watched a few years ago to get started: [flexbox video](https://youtu.be/fYq5PXgSsbE?si=MdJCaHC7Mf536HvC). Good luck!

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width 500px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class='image-wrapper'>
    <div class='image'></div>
    <div class='image'></div>
    <div class='image'></div>
  </div>
  <p>Your Text</p>

</nav>
```